# how to compile head file in robovm ios?

Tags: ios, robovm

We are developing a game on robovm ios.

We must use a third framework.  And the third framework must use some header files and a static library.

If we develop with XCode, we can copy the header files and the static library.  Now we are developing on eclipse and Robovm, we can copy the staic library, but we can't copy the header files!!
So, If we have no header files, the third framework will happen running exception!!

how to solve it?
Any information will be appreciated!
Thanx in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

To use a third party iOS framework in RoboVM, you must first create a Objective-C - Java binding.

You do not need to copy the header files but you will need to use them to create your bindings.

I'm trying to maintain some bindings for famous iOS frameworks and SDKs over here: https://github.com/BlueRiverInteractive/robovm-ios-bindings

Also at the bottom of that page, I've started to write a tutorial on how to create new bindings for frameworks.